# How to make glm object within a function take input variable names and not parameter names?

Tags: r

I've created a function which fits polynomial regression models with increasing degree upto the input degree. I also collect all such models in a list.

After executing this function for a given set of inputs, I want to inspect the model list to calculate the MSE. However I see that the individual models refer to parameter names within the function.

Question: How do I make the glm objects refer to actual variables

Function definition:

```
poly.iter = function(dep,indep,dat,deg){ #Function to iterate through polynomial fits upto input degree
  set.seed(1)
  par(mfrow=c(ceiling(sqrt(deg)),ceiling(sqrt(deg)))) #partitioning the plotting window
  MSE.CV = rep(0,deg)
  modlist = list()
  xvar = seq(from=min(indep),to=max(indep),length.out = nrow(dat))
  for (i in 1:deg){
    mod = glm(dep~poly(indep,i),data=dat)
    #MSE.CV[i] = cv.glm(dat,mod,K=10)$delta[2] #Inside of this function, cv.glm is generating warnings. Googling has not helped as it can typically happen with missing obs but we don't have any in Auto data
    modlist = c(modlist,list(mod))
    MSE.CV[i] = mean(mod$residuals^2) #GLM part is giving 5x the error i.e. delta is 5x of MSE. Not sure why

    plot(jitter(indep),jitter(dep),cex=0.5,col="darkgrey")
    preds = predict(mod,newdata=list(indep=xvar),se=T)
    lines(xvar,preds$fit,col="blue",lwd=2)
    matlines(xvar,cbind(preds$fit+2*preds$se.fit,preds$fit-2*preds$se.fit),lty=3,col="blue")
  }
  return(list("models"=modlist,"errors"=MSE.CV))
}
```

Function Call:

```
output.mpg.disp = poly.iter(mpg,displacement,Auto,9)
```

Inspecting 3rd degree model:

```
> output.mpg.disp[[1]][[3]]

Call:  glm(formula = dep ~ poly(indep, i), data = dat)

Coefficients:
    (Intercept)  poly(indep, i)1  poly(indep, i)2  poly(indep, i)3  
         23.446         -124.258           31.090           -4.466  

Degrees of Freedom: 391 Total (i.e. Null);  388 Residual
Null Deviance:      23820 
Residual Deviance: 7392     AIC: 2274
```

Now I can't use this object inside cv.glm with 'Auto' dataset as it will not recognize indep, dep and i

Comment: Well, your function doesn't work as written. If you define your function in in a fresh R session, `poly.iter(mpg,displacement,Auto,9)` will get you `Error in seq(from = min(indep), to = max(indep), length.out = nrow(dat)) : object 'displacement' not found`, unless you `attach` the data (which is a Bad Idea). You have to do a little work to accept unquoted column names as arguments.

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to have the user input a `formula` like any other modeling function: `poly.iter(mpg ~ displacement, data = Auto, deg =9)`. Then you can edit the formula as needed and pass a proper formula to your internal `glm` call.

Comment: I don't know if you're looking for input on the idea behind this, but it seems highly questionable. I'm reluctant to use quadratic terms, and for higher order polynomials I wouldn't touch them unless I had a nice theoretical equation justifying the choice. Just use a cubic spline or a GAM - it won't be any less interpretable, and it will be more flexible with good theoretical backing.

Comment: Not sure if it's good SO etiquette to have a conversation in comments, so let me know.
Otherwise:
What's the problem with attaching a dataset
I'm just getting started with ISLR, so doing this as part of exercise. But I'm intrigued by the idea that polynomial has less backing than GAM. Any references?

Comment: It's not great to have a conversation in comments, but whatever. As far as `attach` being bad, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067680/903061), this [blog entry](http://sas-and-r.blogspot.com/2011/05/to-attach-or-not-attach-that-is.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+SASandR+%28SAS+and+R%29), `fortunes::fortune("attach")`, the [Google Style Guide for R](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml#attach), etc....

Comment: For poly vs splines, I think [this stats.stackexchange question is good](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/49052/7515), read both answers and comments. I think Frank Harrell's books deal with this, see *Regression Modeling Strategies*. ISLR has it in Section 7.4.5. If you graduate to ESL, they hardly mention polynomial fits (except for the local polynomial regression). Overall, I think high-degree polynomials have the similar advantages and disadvantages to splines, but the advantages aren't quite as good and the disadvantages (extrapolation, bad boundary behavior) are worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `as.formula()` function to transform a string with your formula before calling `glm()`. This will solve your question (How do I make the glm objects refer to actual variables), but I'm not sure if it is enough for the calling `cv.glm` later (I couldn't reproduce your code here, without errors). To be clear, you replace the line

> mod = glm(dep~poly(indep,i),data=dat)

with something like:

> myexp = paste0(dep, "~ poly(", indep, ",", i, ")")
>
> mod = glm(as.formula(myexp), data=dat)

it's required then to make the variables `dep` and `indep` to be characters with names of the variables that you want to refer to (e.g. `indep="displ"`).

Comment: Thank you. While your answer does solve the problem at hand, I was looking for something more elegant that R may have to offer as in making some basic change to how the function is called.

Comment: you can also try this approach: [fix model call in model using as.formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35804514/7774591)